# Mapping AppServerNameList to DataServerNameList in cmd

Tags: cmd

```
AppServerNameList=(........)

DataServerNameList=(..........)
```

I have this list and its mapped one to one . I need to write commands so as to map particular dataserver with app server. I will get dataserver in my file and through that i will call this bat file and will need to get particular appserver. can anyone pls help me for this?

Comment: Thats quite unclear, how are the lists related, postional or is the matching Appserver the one with the attached DataServer number decreased by one?

Comment: Please don't vandalize your post. a) It doesn't help because the edit history is public and b) you will eventually be stopped.

Comment: Why is there a "javascript" tag on this?

Answer (score 0):

Changed parentheses to enclosing double quotes

```
@Echo off&SetLocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
::  Search may be from Argument %1
Set Search=ottvmdx459
set  "UFTAppServerNameList=ottvmdx355 ottvmdx389 ottvmdx452 ottvmdx406 ottvmdx461 ottvmdx489 ottvmdx502 ottvmdx520 ottvmdx526 ottvmdx588 ottvmdx533 ottvmdx537 ottvmdx566 ottvmdx569 ottvmdx573 ottvmdx265 ottvmdx354 ottvmdx360 ottvmdx364 ottvmdx030"
set "UFTDataServerNameList=ottvmdx356 ottvmdx390 ottvmdx453 ottvmdx459 ottvmdx462 ottvmdx490 ottvmdx505 ottvmdx523 ottvmdx527 ottvmdx590 ottvmdx535 ottvmdx563 ottvmdx567 ottvmdx571 ottvmdx592 ottvmdx266 ottvmdx358 ottvmdx361 ottvmdx365 ottvmdx031"

:: Postional
Set /A Pos=0
For %%A in (%UFTAppServerNameList%)  Do Set "App[!Pos!]=%%A"&Set /A Pos+=1
Set /A Pos=0
For %%D in (%UFTDataServerNameList%) Do Call Set "%%D=%%App[!Pos!]%%"&Set /A Pos+=1
Set APP[
Set ott
If     defined %Search% Echo Matching AppServer for DataServer %Search% is !%Search%!
If not defined %Search% Echo DataServer %Search% not in List
```

The first for builds a pseudo array `App[x]` with the postion number and content AppServer
The second one creates environment vars with the name of the Dataserver and content is the corresponding Appserver.

The lines `Set APP[`and `Set ott` are just to demonstrate the arrays with this shortened output:

```
App[0]=ottvmdx355
App[1]=ottvmdx389
App[2]=ottvmdx452
App[3]=ottvmdx406
App[4]=ottvmdx461
..
App[19]=ottvmdx030

ottvmdx031=ottvmdx030
ottvmdx266=ottvmdx265
..
ottvmdx459=ottvmdx406
..
ottvmdx590=ottvmdx588
ottvmdx592=ottvmdx573
Matching AppServer for DataServer ottvmdx459 is ottvmdx406
```

Comment: !Pos! what is the role of exclamation marks? And Thanks for the help that was quick and nice. Amazing stuff. New to command line will learn more and more eventually :)

Comment: @sun Read about `delayed expansion`. Using double %% and a pseudo call has the same reason.

Comment: can't we print the value App array? does it contain any value?

Comment: @sun Batch doesn't know real arrays, the command set will output all single vars begining with the given prefix. I'm puzzled what you do expect from the batch, a table or just the matching AppServer for the DataServer given.

Comment: I just wanna match them and wanna know corresponding Appserver according to data server.

Comment: Set "App[!Pos!]=%%A"     "%%D=%%App[!Pos!]%%"  what does these statements do I am unable to understand.

Comment: @sun Then remove the two lines `set App[` and `set ott`, you may change the last two lines in the batch fit your needs.

Comment: App[!Pos!]=%%A isn't it assigning value to the App[!Pos!]. why isn't it when we try to get the value of App[0] it does not contain any value? because its not an array we are just making to equal to value not literally assigning it?